# ForegroundService can't start - FMX

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

On newer version android I'm change   startService  to  startForegroundService but service can't start.In manifest file is added ForegroundService permission.

```
LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Activity.getBaseContext, TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('myService'));  
TAndroidHelper.Activity.startForegroundService(LIntent);
```

On android 5 work fine:

```
LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Activity.getBaseContext, TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.myService'));
TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService(LIntent);
```

Comment: On later versions of Android, you need to create a notification that ends up being displayed to the user. There's an example of how to do this here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/1c20c99a005e03680d2d52b2fcc85effd990eca1/Demos/CrossPlatformLocation/Service/CPL.ServiceModule.pas#L274